# Ajax calls between old .net 2 aspx site and new .net 4.5 MVC site

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Due to time issues we need to be able to add new button click functionality to an old .net site whilst coding the back end in MVC5 as the rewrite is going to be MVC5 but rewriting the entire page at the moment is too much work.  So I want to be able to call the MVC 5 app from the .net 2 app requesting an object and that be returned.  I have begun investigating Cross Domain Requests, but unfortunately the microsoft example doesn't work, I think they may have moved some pages around.  Could someone point me in the direction of good documentation/Examples or another (maybe better) way of achieving this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you have a separate project going already for the MVC5 app, why not just point the ajax request at the new project's URL?